# How to change xml parameters programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, navbar

I have been working on an app that requires changing the nav menu options based on the User Type. To display the nav menu, i am using NavigationView. The only part i am stuck on is changing the `app:menu` parameter to another menu design (activity_nav_drawer2.xml).

activity_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_nav_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Festivities"
        android:title="Festivities" />
    <!--<item-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/nav_Announcements"-->
        <!--android:title="Announcements" />-->
    <!--<item-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/nav_Payment"-->
        <!--android:title="Payment" />-->
    <!--<item-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/nav_Settings"-->
        <!--android:title="Settings" />-->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_myCode"
        android:title="My Code" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_readCode"
        android:title="Read Code" />
</group>

<!--<group android:checkableBehavior="single">-->
    <!--<item-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/nav_organizer"-->
        <!--android:title="Become an organizer" />-->
    <!--<item-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/nav_Legal"-->
        <!--android:title="Legal" />-->

<!--</group>-->

</menu>
activity_nav2.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Festivities"
        android:title="Create an Event" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_readCode"
        android:title="Read Code" />
</group>



</menu>



MainActivity.java


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

public String eventKey;

private final int REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE = 1;

Intent intent = getIntent();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);

    MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(
            R.id.content_nav,
            mapFragment,
            mapFragment.getTag()
    ).commit();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.set
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    askPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_signOut){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_Festivities) {
        FestivitiesFragment festivitiesFragment = new FestivitiesFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.content_nav,
                festivitiesFragment,
                festivitiesFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_myCode) {


getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_nav,new 
CodeFragment()).commit();



    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.content_nav,
                mapFragment,
                mapFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_readCode) {

        ReadCodeFragment readCodeFragment = new ReadCodeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.content_nav,
                readCodeFragment,
                readCodeFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();


        }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void askPermissions(String permissions, int requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permissions}, 
requestCode);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera already Granted", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

}

}
```

Comment: `navigationView.getMenu().clear(); navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can set visibility of different menu items according to the user type.
Instead of clearing the navigation_menu items, set visibilities for different items accordingly.